# Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.AudioClip' to 'UnityEngine.AudioSource'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

Trying to make random audio play from an array but keep getting this error:

```
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.AudioClip' to 'UnityEngine.AudioSource'
```

This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TonicFunction : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource TonicAudio;
    public AudioClip[] audioClipArray;
   
    void Awake()
    {
        TonicAudio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        TonicAudio = audioClipArray[Random.Range(0,audioClipArray.Length)];
        TonicAudio.PlayOneShot (TonicAudio.clip);
    }
}
```

Beginner at C# so any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `TonicAudio.PlayOneShot (audioClipArray[Random.Range(0,audioClipArray.Length)]);` instead. The error message is pretty clear, you're trying to assign an AudioClip to an AudioSource and they are not compatible types. If it did work then you'd be overwriting the source you setup in the Awake function which is probably not what you wanted either.

Comment: Worked a treat! Thank you very much.

Comment: The error sounds quite self explanatory to me tbh ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following line:

```
TonicAudio = audioClipArray[Random.Range(0,audioClipArray.Length)];
```

Here you're trying to assign an `AudioClip` to something which is an `AudioSource`. That won't work. What you instead want to do is inform the `AudioSource` which clip to play by assigning `clip`and then play it like

```
TonicAudio.clip = audioClipArray[Random.Range(0,audioClipArray.Length)];
TonicAudio.Play();
```

or use `PlayOneShot()` instead by using

```
TonicAudio.PlayOneShot (audioClipArray[Random.Range(0,audioClipArray.Length)]);
```